# Read time as string using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading an excel using pandas in python3. The excel has a column that records, time spent in minutes and second for every record. Second column which reads 3:52 is 3 minutes and 52 seconds spent in that particular step and not "3:52:00 AM" as treated by pandas df. Is there a way to avoid it?
Here is how the data looks in excel:

[image: Excel data]

**Value 56:52:00 is actually 56 minutes and 52 seconds in the excel above (and likewise). Data in the excel columns is strictly in the format defined in the header Time (mm:ss) .. in some sheets it could be Time (hh:mm:ss)**

Here is how I am creating a df:

```
>>> df = xl.parse(sheet_name,header=None,encoding="utf-8", skiprows=3,usecols={1})
>>> df
                       1
0               03:52:00
1               04:52:00
2               05:52:00
3               06:52:00
4               07:52:00
..                   ...
115  1900-01-02 08:52:00
116  1900-01-02 09:52:00
117  1900-01-02 10:52:00
118  1900-01-02 11:52:00
119             00:52:00

>>> df.dtypes
1    object
dtype: object
```

Comment: How are you reading it in pandas? Plaese provide the code. You want the dtype to be a [`TimeDetla`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Timedelta.html) rather than a datetime.

Comment: Can you share your code? Are you passing parse_dates when calling read_csv?

Comment: I am reading excel as:
df = xl.parse(sheet_name,header=None,encoding="utf-8")

Comment: Dan, can you help on how timedelta can be used while reading excel?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. When pandas reads in the excel file using pandas.read_excel() it brings in your duration as a time (HH:MM:SS) with 3 as an hour and 52 as the minutes or as a datetime (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS).

```
      0                 1
0     1              03:52:00    (time object)
118   1   1900-01-02 08:52:00    (datetime object)
119   1              00:52:00    (time object)
```

The code will create a function to convert that time to a timedelta (HH:MM:SS - with 3 as minutes and 52 as seconds) by subtracting midnight (date.min) from the time and dividing that by 60 to get the duration in minutes and seconds rather than hours and minutes.

```
      0      1
0     1   00:03:52    (timedelta object)
118   1   00:56:52    (timedelta object)
119   1   00:00:52    (timedelta object)
```

You can use the timedelta module to modify how the duration is displayed. There's probably a better method that reads the duration in as a TimeDelta, but I'm not sure how to do that.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, date

df=pd.read_excel("filepath")
def convert_to_duration(timeobj):
    if type(timeobj) == datetime:
        datetimemin = datetime.strptime("1899-12-31 00:00:00","%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        return (timeobj - datetimemin)/60
    if type(timeobj) == time:    
        return (datetime.combine(date.min,timeobj)-datetime.min)/60

df[1]=df[1].apply(convert_to_duration)
df
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I understand what it is doing, but in my case col 1 is read as an object dtype and not a time field. Value like 56:52:00 which means 56 minutes, 52 seconds is converted into 1/2/1900 8:52:00 AM (record 118). The function takes a timeobj as input which isnt the case. May be I will try converting that first: >>> df[1]=df[1].apply(convert_to_duration) TypeError: combine() argument 2 must be datetime.time, not str

Answer (score -1):

You can use `converters` kwarg when `read_excel()` and specify column header name you want to convert types to use

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('Data.xlsx', converters={'col':str})
```

or `dtype` kwarg

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('Data.xlsx', dtype={'col':str})
```

Comment: I already tried using converters/dtype. They arent helping here.